# SPFX 1.7.1 webpart is not working on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, spfx

I have created a new SharePoint web part (version 1.7.1). I'm using the react template. The web part is very basic, yet doesn't run on IE 11.

The error returned is 
Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

I don't use find in any of my .ts files, so I found the .find method is being called by the .js files that were transpiled from my .ts files.

Can anybody confirm this to be a bug in SPFX v1.7.1?
If so, is there a solution.

I know this could be fixed by introducing a shim, but I don't know how to configure this for SPFX and can't find any documentation that explains how to do this.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this is because IE 11 doesn't support [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which is used by the React engine.

I have personally used [element-closest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-closest) to polyfill it, although I'm sure other options exist.

```js
// beginning of WebPart code file
import 'element-closest/browser';

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
// rest of the code, etc.
```

Comment: Hi Richard, this doesn't work for me... I have added the poly fill using npm install element-closest, then added the import on all TS files that have import * as React. I still have the error. tslint also complains on this "could not find declaration file for module element-closest/browser..."

Comment: Happy to see it got resolved by the other answer. I realized after reading Zhi Lv's answer that this `Element.closest` issue might not be related, although I definitely have had to polyfill it before for my SPFx solutions. In response to your follow-up question: yes, that's because there were no TypeScript types installed with this package - it would still polyfill correctly, and you could ignore the TSLint complaint.

Comment: unfortunately it did not solve the problem... it's not jquery causing it...

Comment: After eliminating even more packages from my code, i finally found the culprit, which is the "react-if" package... anyone has any experience in fixing that?

Comment: I ended up removing that package entirely and use the "standard" react way of making parts of the rendering complete

Answer (score 0):

With refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill), we can see that the Array.prototype.find() method not support IE browser. But, This method has been added to the ECMAScript 2015 specification and may not be available in all JavaScript implementations yet. However, you can polyfill Array.prototype.find with the following snippet:

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

Besides, as far as I know, when we use [React](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features), by default, the generated react project supports all modern browsers. Support for Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 requires [polyfills](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md). You could check it and import related packages.

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, 

I know a polyfill can solve this... question was... how do you include polyfills into an SPFX?

Some guidance on this part would be a good idea... you may even wonder why MS doesn't support their own proper browser anymore in there own technology (SharePoint).

It's darn frustrating!!!!

Comment: After some investigation, it seems like the problem is coming from including JQUERY to the project. A stock project with REACT does run on IE.  Sorry for the rant!

Comment: so i removed jquery and still have the issue... so how do you use this polyfill?

Comment: You should be able to paste the code snippet into the beginning of the `WebPart.ts` file. It will implement the `Array.find()` method whenever it is called by other code in the web part, including through any import which depends on using Array.find.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your tsconfig.json file: set "target" to "es5" under "compilerOptions".
Typescript will create polyfills for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Use this import in your webpart.ts file.

```
import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.find';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix it for me.